# Escape control characters in a C string

Tags: code-golf, c, code-generation

C/C++ use double quotes `""` for making string literals. If I want the double-quote itself, or certain other characters, to appear in the string, I have to escape them, like so:

```
char *s2 = "This is not \"good\".\nThis is awesome!\n";
```

Here, I used `\"` to represent a double-quote, and `\n` to represent the newline character. So, if my program prints the string, I see

```
This is not "good".
This is awesome!
```

However, if I examine the string in a debugger (Visual Studio or gdb), it shows me the escaped form - the one that would appear in the source code. This is good because it allows to unambiguously identify whether the string contained that `\` backslash character verbatim or as part of an escape-sequence.

The goal of this challenge is to do the same job the debuggers do, but better - the escaped string must contain as few escaping characters as possible! The input to your program (or subroutine) is a string of arbitrary 8-bit bytes, and the output must be suitable for putting into the following boilerplate C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {char str[] =
"### the escaped string goes here ###";
puts(""); // put a breakpoint here to examine the string
puts(str); return 0;}
```

---

For example:

Input (hexdump, 3-byte string): `64 0a 06`

Output: `d\n\6`

Here, `\006` or `\x6` have the same meaning as `\6`, but longer and are therefore unacceptable. Likewise, `\012` and `\xa` have the same meaning as `\n`, but only `\n` is an acceptable encoding for the byte with the value 10.

---

Another example:

Input (hexdump, 5-byte string): `61 0e 38 02 37`

Output: `a\168\0027`

Here, code `0x0e` is escaped as `\16`, and parsed successfully by the C compiler because `8` is not a valid octal digit. However, the code `0x02` is escaped as `\002`, not `\2`, to avoid confusion with the byte `\27`.

Output: `a\168\2\67` - another possible form

---

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) for the exact definition of escaping in C.

Additional (reasonable) rules for this challenge:

- Output must be printable ASCII (no tab characters; no characters with codes above 126)
- The input can be in the form of a string or an array of 8-bit elements. If your language doesn't support it, use the closest alternative. In any case, there should be no UTF encoding for input.
- No [trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C), so no need to escape the `?` character
- No need to handle the null character (code 0) in input - let it be an end-of-string marker, or a regular byte like others - whatever is more convenient
- Code golf: shortest code is the best
- You are not allowed to vandalize the Wikipedia article to bend the rules :)

---

P.S. Summary of the Wikipedia article:

```
Input byte | Output | Note
0x01       | \1     | octal escape
0x02       | \2     | octal escape
0x03       | \3     | octal escape
0x04       | \4     | octal escape
0x05       | \5     | octal escape
0x06       | \6     | octal escape
0x07       | \a     | alarm
0x08       | \b     | backspace
0x09       | \t     | tabulation
0x0a       | \n     | newline
0x0b       | \v     | vertical tabulation
0x0c       | \f     | form feed
0x0d       | \r     | return
0x0e       | \16    | octal escape
0x0f       | \17    | octal escape
...        |        | octal escape
0x1f       | \37    | octal escape
0x22       | \"     | escape with a backslash
0x5c       | \\     | escape with a backslash
0x7f       | \177   | octal escape
0x80       | \200   | octal escape
...        |        | octal escape
0xff       | \377   | octal escape
other      |        | no escape
```

Comment: solutions can be in any language, or must be C ?

Comment: Any language, of course!

Comment: In your hexdump example, I assume you mean 64 0A 06?

Comment: @Alchymist I do! Confusion fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6) 152

First time ever that .reduceRight seems useful. (But probably the good old .map can do better). The point is, I need to see the next character before deciding whether to output a short or long octal escape.

```js
f=s=>[...s].reduceRight((a,c)=>
((x=c.charCodeAt())==34|c==(q='\\')?q+c:x>31&x<127?c:q+('abtnvvr'[x-7]||(a>='0'&a<'8'?512+x:x).toString(8).slice(-3)))+a
)
```